# System DLLs address space

Tags: windows, dll

I wonder what is the range of address space of the system DLLs in the Microsoft Windows operating systems. Also, if a DLL is reallocated, does that mean, that the applications using it would crash?

Answer (score 3):

DLL relocation is a common occurrence and simply means that the DLL is loaded in to memory at a location that is not the preferred base location specified by the DLL (typically because another DLL already occupies the part of the address space that the DLL would "like" to use).  Unless the DLL is making some seriously flawed assumptions about where it will be loaded, all should be well and no crashes will occur.

Use ProcExp or similar to see the address spaces used by the various DLLs of a process.

Comment: I would add that system DLLs _typically_ perfer the 0x70000000 range and above.

Comment: @Paul - cheers, I avoided answering that part as I've not delved into base addresses for years.  :)